# Best way to accomplish a Circular Hub of Links?

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, tree, imagemap

I have been trying to find a tutorial or example of the following image below but am not having much luck. I need a number of links in a circular shape that when hovered over has a popup with information. This also needs to be responsive.

I must be searching for the wrong thing, I've been trying combinations of: **css, circular, circle, node, tree, hub, links, hover**. The closest I have found is this *(which seems overly complicated for what I need)*: http://cytoscape.org/

Is the best solution here an old school image map with jQuery to handle the responsive part, or does someone know of something similar done with CSS?

[image]